# Linking google account with youtube account

Tags: php, youtube-api

I'm trying to use the YouTube Data API to upload videos, but using a Google service account. When I try to upload the video I always get a "NoLinkedYouTubeAccount" error, even though it seems that the google account is linked with youtube.

My problem is that I found a way to upgrade the account to be linked with YouTube here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_profiles#Upgrading_an_Unlinked_Google_Account

But when I run the PUT request it gives me this response:

> HTTP 400
>
> GData`ParseException`Premature end of file.

The headers that I send are the following:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
X-GData-Key: key=<youtube dev key>
GData-Version: 2.1
Content-Type: application/atom+xml; charset=UTF-8
```

I deliberately changed "token" and "youtube dev key"

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, it's not possible to link a YouTube channel to a Service Account. They need to be linked to a full Google Account.

That being said, I can't guess what the response is that you're getting back from your API request. Based on the error message, it sounds like you're not getting back valid XML, but you'd have to turn on logging (say with `Zend_Gdata_YouTube#enableRequestDebugLogging()`) to or sniff the network traffic to see exactly what you're getting back.

Comment: I'm not using Zend_GData instead I'm using the google php sdk. To my knowledge it can link a youtube account to a service account http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/10/introducing-google-account-support-and.html

Comment: The Google APIs PHP client library works with v3 of the API. The Zend GData client library works with v2 of the API. The method call to link a Google Account to a new YouTube channel is part of v2 of the API, so I assumed you were using the Zend client library. In any case, I really don't think you can link a service account to a YouTube channel, even with the v2 API call. The last I checked, you can only link a full Google Account.